# In Cypress, After an UI operation how to check a particular API call is triggered in Network tab and verify the Status as 200

Tags: cypress

I have a web application to perform the update operation with the help of a **Update button** in UI mode.

During that time list of APIs are loaded into the Network tab with XHR type as below. I have to verify one of the API put call is triggered and the status is passed.

[image]

> url.toString() --  https://abcdef.execute-api.ue-east-2.amazonaws.com/stg2

*It contains the RequestedURL value. I manually verified that in Network tab for that particular API put call. Then kept that in cypress.json and reading the url to the current class*

> Base URL for the UI operation: https://abc-stg2.awsdev.fgh.com/

*Note: The both url are modified and dummy one, since it is confidential to share. The understanding is API calls are in AWS and the UI urls are in other environment*

**Try #1**

```
// After the UI operation
cy.intercept('PUT',url.toString()).as('urupdate')
  
cy.wait('@urupdate',{requestTimeout:20000})
  .its('status')
  .should('be.eq',200)
```

Output:

[image]

**Try #2**

```
cy.intercept('PUT', url.toString(), (req) => {
   if (req.body.status == 200) {
       cy.log('pass')
    }
})
```

Output:

The log is not getting printed and till the if statement everything is getting passed

How can we verify the particular API is triggered and the status is 200?

I have gone through the *intercept* as above and other stuffs in Cypress. But that does not get me the solution. Share your suggestions

Comment: "But that does not get me the solution" => how does it look then? What error do you see in the test runner? There's nothing wrong with your solution #1, so it might only be a case when the url doesn't match.

Comment: @pavelsaman I have updated the question with the output and further information about *url.toString()*

Comment: The Base url and the url I need to verify under the Network is different (update the question). Is there an alternate way to handle this scenario.

Comment: I think we need to see the whole test.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan any updated about this, have you fixed your problem?

Comment: @Mona101ma No I haven't get the proper solution

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan check this, it helped me to fix my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778215/cy-intercept-for-post-endpoints-with-query-parameters/69778583?noredirect=1#comment123345237_69778583