# cy.intercept() for post endpoints with query parameters

Tags: cypress

My test cases were flaky because sometimes the test interacts with the element before it appears on the screen, instead of static waits, I decided to use `cy.intercept()` to wait for the triggered request before interacting with the elements.

I tried it first with a PUT request with some path parameters, and it worked fine and on cypress runner I saw the alias represents the endpoint correctly

```
 cy.intercept('PUT', `https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program/**`).as('saveProgram');
 cy.wait('@saveProgram');
```

[image]

I tried the same thing for a post endpoint that requires a query params in the URL but it didn't work. In the runner I can't see the alias assigned to endpoint as in the below screenshot.

```
 cy.intercept('POST', `https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program?clientId=*`)
                    .as('createProgram');
 cy.wait('@createProgram');
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like the url is not intercepted correctly. Can you try this `https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program?clientId*`

Comment: @AlapanDas
not working, even when I tried to pass the static value for the query param as a test.
`https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program?clientId=36`

Comment: @AlapanDas It got fixed as I mentioned in the answer below. Thanks 

Answer (score 11):

There are different ways to match, namely:

- literal string
- glob pattern
- regex pattern
- route matcher object

If one doesn't work, I recommend:

1. simplifying the match pattern, that will make it more permissive, you can later work on building more restrictive version
2. trying a different matching method

In this order.

I also noticed that your example has `cy.wait()` directly after `cy.intercept()`. Most likely, you need the action that triggers the request in between these commands. I don't know if you simplified your code just for the sake of this question, or if that really is your code. If the latter, you need to rework it:

```js
cy
  .intercept(...)
  .as('createProgram');

// your other code that triggers the request

cy
  .wait('@createProgram'); // wait for the response
```

Now, let's see what are some other option you can write that matching pattern:

```js
cy
  .intercept('POST', /\/api\/program\/v1\/program\?clientId=\d+/)
  .as('createProgram');
```

Try to avoid the full url, it usually only clutters your code and in most cases it is not necessary.

```js
cy
  .intercept('POST', 'program?clientId=*')
  .as('createProgram');
```

Really permissive, but if you make this work, you can work towards more restrictive matching pattern later (if you need one).

```js
cy
  .intercept({
    pathname: '/api/program/v1/program'
    query: {
      clientId: '36'
    }
  })
  .as('createProgram');
```

Any of these matched correctly?

There are countless other option in the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept).

Comment: unfortunately, none of them is working.

Comment: It got fixed as I mentioned in the answer below. Thanks 

Comment: @Mona101ma: good you solved it. My first code snippet actually refers exactly to this problem.

Comment: my bad, I didn't notice that 

Answer (score 3):

This article helped me to solve this issue https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/

The problem happens because `cy.intercept()` in my case was called while the request is already in progress and therefore it wasn't intercepted.

The workaround was calling `cy.intercept()` earlier in the test case before triggering the xhr request.

Answer (score 3):

I see this question was already answered above, but perhaps I can add additional debugging options for those who have similar problems.  The current version of Cypress (mine is 10.8.0) includes the [Minimatch Library](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) . If you are unsure if the string you are providing to `cy.intercept()` will match the desired route, you can use

`Cypress.minimatch(target: string, pattern: string, options?: MinimatchOptions);`

To do this, start running your cypress tests.  When it opens the browser of your choice to start running the tests, open up the console and and type (for this example):

`Cypress.minimatch('https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program?clientId=36', 'https://api.dev.myapp.com/api/program/v1/program?clientId=*', { matchBase: true})`

in this case the console will return `true` so you know that the string you are providing `cy.intercept()` is not the issue and the problem lies elsewhere.  For more info check out the docs here [Cypress.minimatch](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/minimatch).